# Which scale types are available in ink contract metadata

Tags: ink

I am trying to write a decoder for data which generates by `contracts` pallet.
For this purpose i have to convert metadata types to types which are supported by scale decoder which i use. Where i can found information about types available in contract's metadata?

Now i have this code but i am not sure that it will cover all possible types in contract's metadata:

```
import {Type, TypeKind} from "@subsquid/scale-codec"
import {TypeDef} from "./interfaces"
import assert from "assert"


export function normalizeTypes(types: TypeDef[]): Type[] {
    return types.map(type => {
        let keys = Object.keys(type.type.def)
        assert(keys.length == 1)
        switch(keys[0]) {
            case 'primitive':
                return {
                    kind: TypeKind.Primitive,
                    primitive: type.type.def.primitive.toUpperCase(),
                }
            case 'composite':
                return {
                    kind: TypeKind.Composite,
                    fields: type.type.def.composite.fields,
                }
            case 'array':
                return {
                    kind: TypeKind.Array,
                    len: type.type.def.array.len,
                    type: type.type.def.array.type,
                }
            case 'tuple':
                return {
                    kind: TypeKind.Tuple,
                    tuple: type.type.def.tuple,
                }
            case 'variant':
                return {
                    kind: TypeKind.Variant,
                    variants: type.type.def.variant.variants.map((variant: any) => {
                        return {
                            ...variant,
                            fields: variant.fields || [],
                        }
                    }),
                }
            default:
                throw new Error(`Unexpected type '${keys[0]}'`)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available types come from the
[`scale-info`](https://github.com/paritytech/scale-info) crate. The types get broken down
into one of eight categories, as you can see
[here](https://github.com/paritytech/scale-info/blob/e4de349a3f1088280a1266c860db72f204d0bba8/src/ty/mod.rs#L247).

```rust
pub enum TypeDef {
    /// A composite type (e.g. a struct or a tuple)
    Composite,
    /// A variant type (e.g. an enum)
    Variant,
    /// A sequence type with runtime known length.
    Sequence,
    /// An array type with compile-time known length.
    Array,
    /// A tuple type.
    Tuple,
    /// A Rust primitive type.
    Primitive,
    /// A type using the [`Compact`] encoding
    Compact,
    /// A type representing a sequence of bits.
    BitSequence,
}
```

However, we realize that it sucks to have to hardcode this validation in your code. We've
recently started working on a JSON Schema for the ink! metadata so that things like types
can be programatically verified. [Here's a preview](https://gist.github.com/HCastano/6fe5103c7bac2a7d7f9853dc78e93889) of the schema for ink!'s metadata.

If you dig in there you can see that types are described by `PortableType` and
`TypeDef_for_PortableForm`. You should be able to use those to decode the given types.

```json
"TypeDef_for_PortableForm": {
  "description": "The possible types a SCALE encodable Rust value could have....",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "description": "A composite type (e.g. a struct or a tuple)",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "composite"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "composite": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeDefComposite_for_PortableForm"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "description": "A variant type (e.g. an enum)",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "variant"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "variant": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeDefVariant_for_PortableForm"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "description": "A sequence type with runtime known length.",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "sequence"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "sequence": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeDefSequence_for_PortableForm"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "description": "An array type with compile-time known length.",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "array"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "array": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeDefArray_for_PortableForm"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "description": "A tuple type.",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "tuple"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "tuple": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "uint32",
            "minimum": 0.0
          }
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "description": "A Rust primitive type.",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "primitive"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "primitive": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeDefPrimitive"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "description": "A type using the [`Compact`] encoding",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "compact"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "compact": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeDefCompact_for_PortableForm"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "description": "A type representing a sequence of bits.",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "bitsequence"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "bitsequence": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeDefBitSequence_for_PortableForm"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```